# Array Caps (2 dimensions)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to use the array modifier. When I use the  object in the first image the result is a closed shape but it creates unwanted faces between the copies.

[image]

When I use the object in the second image the final result doesn't have a closed perimeter.

[image]

[image]

The use of caps is easily applicable in one dimension array. In a 2-dimension array things become complicated. Is there an effective and not over-complicated solution?

Comment: what exactly is your problem in the first case? because you know they are there? Do you have texturing problems?

Comment: I don't think there's any easy solution, is it a problem if at the end you apply the Array and fill the sides?

Comment: It is for 3d printing and the geometry should be manifold without internal faces.

Comment: @moonboots I want it to be non destructive. The size of the object will be variable.

Comment: Isn’t there an option in the array modifier that lets you add a cap object or something?

Comment: @TheLabCat Yes, it is very effective for 1 dimension array, but when  you add second array the result it's not as expected.

Comment: @artos use just a vertical wall as the cap object?

Comment: you could use geometry nodes. Use your 2nd option, and use GN with planes to fill your caps.

Answer (score 2):

For the geometry you're showing, aiming for something non-destructive but simple, I would make the side walls with a rim-only solidify, and then weld the two copies of the sidewall that would be created by that solidify:

[image]

Showing 0 vertices non-manifold after convert to mesh.

For a small trade-off of non-destructive vs simple, you can drive the thickness of the solidify modifier from the distance between vertex-parented empties.

For different geometry, with normals that weren't at right angles to the main plane at the margins, this technique would still be possible, but more complex:

[image]

We do a miniscule solidify (because normals depend on non-zero-area-faces) with assignment to a VG, then modify our rim normals to point properly so we can do a displace from custom normals, weld (which will set some of our rim verts to weight 0.5) then finally mask away the unmerged rim verts.

The normals are measured from empty to origin, so the empty should be at the origin except for the Z axis, and should be parented to the object.

Comment: I want a more universal solution, that can be applied with more complex shapes.

Answer (score 1):

i made just one side (the other can be made accordingly)

[image]

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Start with a cube, rescale it if necessary
2. Subdivide its top face into squares with loopcut
3. Select the square faces, resulting from step 2,  you want to extrude and extrude them down.

Done! 
[image]

[image]
 I removed one face to show no internal faces were created. You need to calculate the number of sub-squares to match the size and number of the impressions, but it still is simpler than others presented here.
 If the above is still too much fuss for you then use array, your top image, with Merge option checked select all internal (or **non-manifold**) faces by hand and delete them with Faces Only option.
 
Regarding your comment: use array as in your second and third image, extrude **the edges** of the mesh arrayed and close it with the bottom face.

Comment: Thank you, for effort. I know how to model a simple shape like this I want a more universal solution, that can be applied with more complex shapes and it has to be scalable. This was a simple object for reference.

Comment: @artos: No problemo, some speed modeling did the job.